# How does SSL indentify the client?

Tags: security, ssl

I'm trying to understand SSL at a high level.

The way I understand it the entire request is encrypted.  When the server receives the request how does it know where the request came from?

I was assuming it used some sort of unique identifier such as session key but if the request is encrypted then how would it know how to decrypt the request if it doesn't know where it originated from?

Comment: I am recommending closure of this question as it relates to server management or rather web server administration or networking, depending on the way you look at it. Questions that do not directly relate to programming or pose a programming question or a question related to programming tools or a library are generally off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 2):

SSL simply provides authentication of the remote host (web server) and negotiated encryption in most cases. There are times when a client may provide a client certificate, which is then verified to be correct through SSL handshaking.

Without a client certificate, SSL does not authenticate the client and it simply can only be sure that the original sender is still the sender in the given session, as it possesses the encryption key originally agreed upon. That encryption key is necessary to continue communication and so if the client can communicate, it has the key, and is thus still the original client or some attacker that compromised the stream (unlikely with secure algorithms).

With a client certificate, SSL can authenticate the client and provide identity information to the web server, which may be consumed by a web application and used internally for whatever purpose.